# RewriteRule only works for home page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, s3-rewrite-rules

I have this RewriteRule which create a permanent redirection from example1.com to example2.com

In the htaccess of example1.com I have these rules:

```
    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirection works fine for https://www.example1.com/ (it gets redirected to https://www.example2.com). But it does not work for  https://www.example1.com/about-us

I expect https://www.example1.com/about-us to be redirected to https://www.example2.com/about-us

Comment: Your rule looks like it should work if it doesn't  then try clearing your browser cache or check your other rules that are placed before this one in htaccess

Comment: @starkeen I try in a clean browser, incognito, etc. There are no more rules in my htaccess. But it still does not work.

Comment: Is `/about-us` is directory ?

Comment: @starkeen no, it's a wordpress page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rewrite to this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```